# Adding Search Bar in PowerPoint using VBA which searches the word entered by the user in a particular slide and highlights it?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I wish to add a search bar in my presentation which searches a particular word entered by the user in a particular slide and highlight it. That word will have a hyperlink attached to it which will take it to the meaning of the word.

I am a newbie in VBA. I have this code, need necessary changes to make it work.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
Dim osld As Slide
Dim oshp As Shape
Dim b_found As Boolean
Dim oTxtRng As TextRange
Dim sTextToFind As String

sTextToFind = Me.TextBox1.Text


 If KeyCode = 13 Then 'ENTER PRESSED
 If Me.TextBox1.Text <> "" Then
     For Each osld In Application.ActivePresentation.Slides(5)
         For Each oshp In osld.Shapes
             If oshp.HasTextFrame Then
                 If oshp.TextFrame.HasText Then
                     If InStr(UCase(oshp.TextFrame.TextRange), UCase(Me.TextBox1.Text)) > 0 Then
                     SlideShowWindows(1).View.GotoSlide (osld.sectionIndex(5))
                     Set oTxtRng = oshp.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters(InStr(oshp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text, sTextToFind), Len(sTextToFind))
                     Debug.Print oTxtRng.Text
                     With oTxtRng
                      .Font.Bold = True
                 End With

             b_found = True
          Exit For
       End If
    End If
 End If
 Next oshp
 If b_found = True Then Exit For
 Next osld
 End If
 If b_found = False Then MsgBox "Not found"
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for posting your code; in addition, you should explain what exactly the problem with it is.  Does it not compile, does it do the wrong stuff, does it not do anything ... ?  I'm assuming that this is supposed to run in slide show view and that there's a textbox on one of the slides. That may be obvious to you but not to the world at large.  Better to make it clear up front, save everybody some time.

Give this a try.  Note that it'll only find the first instance of the word in question within a given text range.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
Dim osld As Slide
Dim oshp As Shape
Dim b_found As Boolean
Dim oTxtRng As TextRange
Dim sTextToFind As String

'sTextToFind = Me.TextBox1.Text

 If KeyCode = 13 Then 'ENTER PRESSED
 If Me.TextBox1.Text <> "" Then
   sTextToFind = Me.TextBox1.Text
     'For Each osld In Application.ActivePresentation.Slides(5)
    For Each oshp In ActivePresentation.Slides(5).Shapes
        If oshp.HasTextFrame Then
            If oshp.TextFrame.HasText Then
                If InStr(UCase(oshp.TextFrame.TextRange), UCase(Me.TextBox1.Text)) > 0 Then
                    'SlideShowWindows(1).View.GotoSlide (osld.sectionIndex(5))
                    SlideShowWindows(1).View.GotoSlide (5)
                    Set oTxtRng = oshp.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters(InStr(oshp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text, sTextToFind), Len(sTextToFind))
                    Debug.Print oTxtRng.Text
                    With oTxtRng
                     .Font.Bold = True
                    End With

                    b_found = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next oshp
'    If b_found = True Then Exit For
'    Next osld
 End If
 If b_found = False Then MsgBox "Not found"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The problem with the code is 
    
For Each osld In Application.ActivePresentation.Slides(5) is showing an error. What I want is let's say there are 20 words written in slide number 5, I want this search bar to be in slide 1 and the user can search either of those 20 words using that.

Comment: Yes, I assumed that that would provoke an error.  See the rewritten version.

Comment: It works perfectly. Thank you. Is there any way I can reach out to you directly regarding the same if I have any other querries?

Comment: Another post here would be best. I check in here regularly.